# Are Teams [Side Panel] Meeting Apps supported on the Web version?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I was working on a Teams Meeting App and as using a Teams Web web client to validate the changes when I found that the [`sidePanel` functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/create-apps-for-teams-meetings?tabs=json#sidepanel)  did not show up at all,
Also not in ring 3.6/preview

After opening up in the full client this started working straight away.

The documentation only mentions missing functionality on **mobile**, and limits for **anon/guest users**,
but no mention regarding missing functions on the web client.

relevant section from the app manifest:

```json
    "configurableTabs": [
      {
        "configurationUrl": "https://somewhere.ngrok.io/meeting/config.html",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "scopes": [
          "groupchat"
        ],
        "context": [
          "privateChatTab",
          "meetingChatTab",
          "meetingDetailsTab",
          "meetingSidePanel"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "identity",
      "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
```

Comment: the in-meeting app experience is not supported in Teams Web Client as of now.

Comment: How did you manage to add your app to the sidepanel in the full client? I don't see that option like in the screenshots Microsoft provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the in-meeting app experience is currently (18.11.2020) not available in Teams Web client, only in the native app.

Comment: I suggest to add de date or year / month to this answer to make it more useful in the coming period as features keep updating